# Errors thrown in console when using ng-bind-html with $sce in filter

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am working on a chat application where we want to filter the chats on the client side to clean swear words and HTML and from what I can tell in Angular 1.2.0-rc2 `ng-bind-html` should auto-clean any text you pass to it. Also from the docs I see you can pass `$sce.trustAsHtml(input)` to ng-bind html (in theory) to render HTML as they removed `ng-bind-html-unsafe` in 1.2.0.

My issue is in my JSFiddle I am not seeing ng-bind-html clean html. I can pass a string with a link in it to `ng-bind-html` and it will render the link. I am trying to work on a short tags filter (So moderators can do something to the effect of `[url|http://google.com|Google]` and have its generated HTML wrapped in `$sce.trustAsHtml(input)`.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pa4XV/

You can see that I have the following on `$scope`:

```
$scope.chats = [
  {from: 'test', message: 'Chat Message 1'},
  {from: 'test', message: 'Chat Message 2 <a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>'},
  {from: 'test2', message: 'Chat Message [url|http://google.com|Google]'}
];
```

I would expect the 3rd message to display a link and the 2nd message to be caught by ng-bind-html (as it would not be wrapped by `$sce`) but in the Fiddle I am seeing both get rendered. This is very confusing to me as this is not the behavior I see in my code. The only big difference between my Fiddle and my code is that $scope.chats comes from Firebase instead of being hardcoded and my `shortTags` filter has code wrapping it checking if the user is a moderator or not (It only replaces short tags for mods).

There is a very high possibility that I am doing this "wrong" or there is a better way to do this kind of thing in angular (I started with a $watchCollection adding a .safeMessage param but that caused looping, which I understand now) and I am more than happy to solve this problem in a different manner if that is the better way. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Something has went wrong in your fiddle, it seems to be empty.

Comment: @DoctorMick Thank you catching that, updated! http://jsfiddle.net/pa4XV/

Comment: I'm fairly sure that all ng-bind-html "cleans" are script tags and things that can cause possible XSS attacks, which probably explains why your link is still being displayed. By using $sce you are stating that XSS is not a concern and the content is trusted (not true of chat messages, surely). It's a bit of a catch 22 because if you don't use ng-bind-html, you get everything escaped, but with it you get nothing escaped. You probably need your own directive to render the content, and to call $sanitize (not $sce) before applying your shortTags filter, but surely someone has a lib for short tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed 3 days ago by the commit : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e2068ad426075ac34c06c12e2fac5f594cc81969